# How to generate reports for Android Automation

Tags: android, unit-testing, automated-tests, robotium

I have a Robotium test cases that I would like to run nightly using automation tool, however I am not sure if it can be done without manually running it through Eclipse first. Is there a build script that would enable me to run the Robotium test cases automatically on nightly basis. Ideally this test cases would run directly on the device as we want to test compatibility across different Android OS Platform.

*How can I run the test cases automatically? Is there any build script for Android out there that would enable me to do what I need to do?"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you have to use the java io to generate report and store it in the android and after the report is generated you just have to pull the file out.